# recursive function transform nested array

Tags: php, laravel

Im my laravel project I have this nested array that needs to be updated (transformed - for the frontend):

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:3 [
        "entity_id" => 931  
        "entity" => "user"
        "children" => array:2 [
            0 => array:2 [
                "entity_id" => 5    
                "entity" => "location"
            ]
            1 => array:2 [
                "entity_id" => 932  
                "entity" => "user"
            ]
        ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
        "entity_id" => 486  
        "entity" => "user"
    ]
]
```

EXPECTED ARRAY:

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
        "id" => 931
        "text" => "Test User 1"
        "type" => "user"
        "children" => array:2 [
            0 => array:3 [
                "id" => 5
                "text" => "Location 1"
                "type" => "location"
            ]
            1 => array:3 [
                "id" => 932
                "text" => "Test User 2"
                "type" => "user"
            ]
        ]
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
        "id" => 486
        "text" => "Test User 3"
        "type" => "user"
    ]
]
```

I have created a recursive function for this job

```
public function getNewStructure($tree, &$output) {
    foreach($tree as $data) {
        $output[] = array(
            'id' => $data['entity_id'],
            'text' => $data['user'] === 'user' ? User::find($data['entity_id'])->name : Location::find($data['entity_id'])->name,
            'type' => $data['entity']
        );
        
        $this->getNewStructure($data['children'] ?? [], $output);
    }
    
    return $output;
}
```

but it not returns as expected:

```
array:4 [
    0 => array:3 [
        "id" => 931
        "text" => "Test User 1"
        "type" => "user"        
    ]
    0 => array:3 [
        "id" => 5
        "text" => "Location 1"
        "type" => "location"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
        "id" => 932
        "text" => "Test User 2"
        "type" => "user"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
        "id" => 486
        "text" => "Test User 3"
        "type" => "user"
    ]
]
```

How can I add the children to the $output array in the recursive function ???

I have tried by adding the children key:

```
$this->getNewStructure($data['children'] ?? [], $output['children']);
```

as when iterating again it will push the current array in the right place.... but is not working...

Comment: Do not post your answer in the question. Please revert your last edit, and add that code as an answer below. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site; having the answer within the question breaks that 

Answer (score 0):

I fixed

```
public function getNewStructure($tree, &$output) {
    foreach($tree as $data) {
        $element = array(
            'id' => $data['entity_id'],
            'text' => $data['user'] === 'user' ? User::find($data['entity_id'])->name : Location::find($data['entity_id'])->name,
            'type' => $data['entity']
        );

        if(is_array($data['children']) && count($data['children']) > 0) {
            $element['children'] = $this->getNewStructure($data['children'], $element['children']);
        }
        
        $output[] = $element;
    }
    
    return $output;
}
```